# Установка input type="color" в неопределенное

Tags: html5

В `html5` появился тип `color` для `input` по умолчанию он установлен в положение `#000000` Таким образом он всегда передает черный цвет в форму. Как выставить неопределенное значение, если цвет не выбирали?

Comment: Похоже, поле не может иметь значение "никакой цвет". Вижу выход - вводить флаг `isColorChanged`, изменение в true которого вешать на изменение цвета, а на бэкенде уже проверять этот флаг, выставлен ли цвет пользователем или пришёл дефолтным.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color *" The value ... is never empty"*

Comment: Да, примерно такое решение мне  тоже пришло в голову. Но ведь получается это косяу в html))) Недоработка

Comment: Меня это в дикий восторг приводит) И спасибо за документацию